# SharePoint 2013 Task List Status cannot complete after due date

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-server, list-form, task-list

I have task list where the status remains "Not Started" if i try to complete the task after the due date has crossed. Even when i write and event receiver and try to overwrite the field task status to "Completed" it still remains as "Not started" but if the due date has not crossed everything works fine and the task gets completed successfully. Is this a normal behavior of SharePoint task list or am i missing something somewhere? Can anyone help? Thanks.......

Comment: I do face the same issue...Did u find any solutiion ? Or is that a sharepoint behaviour ? Is there any alternative solution for this ? Thanks in advance

Comment: in my case the SharePoint field validator was set which was causing the issue after removing it everything started working fine